# How to make copies of default lists and libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, template, default

We are trying to copy the default Pages and Documents to another SharePoint subsite. In SharePoint online there is no option to make a template of these. In SharePoint Designer, we were able to make a template of the default Pages list, but it did not show up when creating a new App.

Comment: What is your use-case? I do not see the point in copying the 'default' as you can deploy a new library which contains the defaults.

Comment: We are trying to copy the contents of a Pages list to a new site while still keeping the metadata attached to the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the library/list as a template then create instances from sub-site:

- [How to create and save a SharePoint document library template](https://support.macroview.com.au/hc/en-us/articles/360000345875-How-to-create-and-save-a-SharePoint-document-library-template)

Turn to classical UI then add an app, you will be able to find the corresponding templates.

Comment: As I stated in my question, SharePoint does not allow for the creation of Templates from these default libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Export-PnPListToProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/export-pnplisttoprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps) and then apply the contents using [Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps).

You can do this in an automated fashion by creating an [Azure Automation runbook](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/automation/manage-runbooks) and calling that from a Power Automate Flow using an HTTP action.